# Request.Form serialize to JSON and loop through all properties in JSON

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .NET Core Web API project and one API query that accepts random form data (without files). I need to serialize form data to JSON and pass to the service. Then in service I need to loop through each JSON property and do some handling.

I'm trying something like this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request.Form); //it isn't simple JSON
```

and

```
var jsonObject = new JObject();
var data = Request.Form.ToList();
for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{        
    jsonObject.Add(data[i].Key, data[i].Value.ToString());
}
```

Are there any other ways to do that? What about loop through all JSON properties?

Comment: [`JObject.Properties()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Properties.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can serialize directly Request.Form to JSON.

But could you try like this way ?

```
public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this NameValueCollection col)
{
  var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

  foreach (var key in col.Keys)
  {
    dict.Add(key, col[key]);
  }

  return dict;
}
```

then

```
var dictionary = Request.Form.ToDictionary();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Formatting.Indented);
```

then on the service deserialize your string.

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

Comment: `IFormCollection` doesn't contain definition for `CopyTo`